# Ordering of category elements

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, algorithm

I have a list of categories that I publish to a UI from database.

In the UI in stead of entering order for category elements, I want to be able able to use images to change the order of category.

I understand that I have to change the Order field of category items in the database and be aware that categories can be deleted.

What s a good way of getting this done ?

eg;

```
ID  - Category - Order
1      Foo        DOWN
2      Bar        UP DOWN
3      Car        UP DOWN
4      Jar        UP
```

For item with id 3, if I click on UP, I want following:

```
ID  - Category - Order
1      Foo        DOWN
2      Car        UP DOWN
3      Bar        UP DOWN
4      Jar        UP
```

Any ideas?

Category info is stored in the database with Id,Category,Order fields. I just need an idea how I can do this easily.

Comment: Why don't you store `Order` as integer value?

Comment: well duhhh, how else i d do it?

Comment: What is your question exactly ? Writing the SQL to do this ? Writing the C# code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply swap the value of the `Order` column for the involved rows.

Comment: swap? should i add the order number to parameter for up and down? i was thinking something more sophisticated.

Comment: What you really want to do is swap the order of two items when the user clicks the button - so swapping the Order number is the simplest solution. Why do you need it to be "sophisticated".

Comment: if i dont put the order of the upper item to the UP button and DOWn correspondingly, I would need a SQL to get it done right? how else I would know the element before the current one if I m deleting categories.